# Have i done something to make picasa embedded gallery slow or is it just slow?

Tags: html, css

This is my first website I'm sorry if I've done something incorrectly. All help very much appreciated.

**The problem.**
I am currently using [picasa's](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/getEmbed) web album. ( I use this so my client should easily be able to update the pictures being show). When I load the page It does take a second or two for the album to show up. Yet on other computers it just does not show up at all.

**The question**
Why does the embedded gallery app show up for me but not for others?
Also Is there a better alternative.

[My website Gallery](http://www.duhuh.co.uk/gallary.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open the [JavaScript console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) you're greeted with:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/114335947299595812751/albumid/5880485482955492337?kind=photo&alt=rss

This means that the feed you're trying to load can't be found (or can no longer be found, at any rate).

To resolve this you'll need to point your embed code (on line 23 of your gallary.html file) a working address.

I imagine it loads for you because your page is cached. Try <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to do a hard refresh; failing that, clear your browser's cache and refresh.

Comment: Okay I did that and I got the same message as you. I think I found the problem could be that others were not authorised to see the gallery, and hence when i cleared my cache it logged me out of google and hence could not see it thanks. Narrowed down the problem i'm getting :).

Comment: Ah, I was going to mention that the gallery may be private, but I've not sure how Picasa works so didn't want to jump to conclusions.